# Making directory in php

Tags: php

I have a problem when I want to upload pictures and to make new directory which does not exist it doesnt make folder $gallery_name, it store pictures in uploads/galerije/$username instead of uploads/galerije/$username/$gallery_name.
Can anyone help me?

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$gallery_name = $_POST['gallery_name'];

if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ( $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ) {
        $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if ($file_size > 2097152) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }

        $desired_dir = "uploads/galerije/" . $username . "/" . $gallery_name;

        if (empty($errors)) {
            if (!is_dir($desired_dir)) {
                mkdir($desired_dir, 0777); // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (!is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name);
                header("location: index.php");
            }
        }
        else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Make sure that your PHP user has permissions to create directories/files.

Comment: You should have mkdir create the directories recursively like the answers given, however I don't think that explains why they get moved to the wrong directory. does `$_POST['gallery_name'];` even exist? You can see with `var_dump($_POST['gallery_name']);`

Comment: Be careful! You use user input without any verification in file operations. An evil user can simply upload any file into any directory of your webspace. For example, set $_POST['gallery_name'] to something like "../../../", upload a file called index.php and you're done.

Comment: @Jasper I dont get error, but when I check in directory where are pictures. It make uploads/galerije/$username but it wont make uploads/galerije/$username/$gallery_name

Comment: @immulatin it exist, i check it already

Comment: @a4c8b thanks for that i will correct, but first to fix this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell mkdir() to create the directories recursively if they're not already existant.

Try passing `true` to your mkdir() function:

```
mkdir($desired_dir, 0777, true);
```

The [php documents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) specifically state that mkdir() doesn't deal with recursive directories by default, as of 5.0.0 you can pass in the argument to change that

Answer (score 2):

You are using [`is_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) here:

```
if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
```

When you should use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). Maybe that's *part* of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

so, to create directories recursively You might do like this:

```
mkdir("$desired_dir", 0777, true);
```